# StructureMap: Is there a way to get a non-static container?

Tags: structuremap

All examples of StructureMap that I've seen  use the static ObjectFactory class to initialize and resolve objects.  I however would like to pass around a reference to my container.  I assume that ObjectFactory is just a singleton wrapper for a non-static object.  But where is it?

Comment: Short answer: `new Container()` Long answer: [http://docs.structuremap.net/UsingTheContainerOutsideOfObjectFactory.htm](http://docs.structuremap.net/UsingTheContainerOutsideOfObjectFactory.htm)